# Qt not finding slot

Tags: c++, qt

I have a basic window that has a slot `fileNew()`. When I run my app, I get the following error:

> QObject::connect: No such slot QMainWindow::fileNew()

Why is it not finding the slot?

**SdiWindow.h**

```
class SdiWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
  SdiWindow(QWidget * parent = 0);

private slots:
  void fileNew();

private:
  QTextEdit * docWidget;
  QAction * newAction;

  void createActions();
  void createMenus();
};
```

**SdiWindow.cpp**

```
SdiWindow::SdiWindow(QWidget * parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
  setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
  setWindowTitle( QString("%1[*] - %2").arg("unnamed").arg("SDI") );

  docWidget = new QTextEdit(this);
  setCentralWidget(docWidget);

  connect(
    docWidget->document(), SIGNAL(modificationChanged(bool)),
    this, SLOT(setWindowModified(bool))
  );

  createActions();
  createMenus();
  statusBar()->showMessage("Done");
}

void SdiWindow::createActions()
{
  newAction = new QAction( QIcon(":/images/new.png"), tr("&New"), this );
  newAction->setShortcut( tr("Ctrl+N") );
  newAction->setStatusTip( tr("Create a new document") );
  connect(newAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(fileNew()));
}

void SdiWindow::createMenus()
{
  QMenu * menu = menuBar()->addMenu( tr("&File") );
  menu->addAction(newAction);
}

void SdiWindow::fileNew()
{
  (new SdiWindow())->show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SdiWindow needs to have the Q_OBJECT macro as its first line.

```
class SdiWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT
public: ....
```

you will also have to use **moc** on the header file. The [moc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/moc.html) tool generates all the required C++ code for the signal and slot framework.

The generated moc code must be compiled and known to the linker. I do this by including the generated file in my implementation file like this

```
#include SdiWindow.h
#include SdiWindow.moc
```

drescherjm also suggests just compiling it on its own.

EDIT: In this case you're inheriting from QMainWindow, for future reference your class will need to inherit from QObject in some way to be able to use the signal/slot framework.

Comment: The including of the .moc is not necessarily needed. For me I have moc_classname.cxx. And these are sources of the project.

Comment: @drescherjm I've run into issues when I've not included it. Although it's possible that I've only forgotten to do so when calling things generated by moc...

Comment: @drescherjm I just tried commenting it out and I get linker errors. I believe that your moc code just needs to be compiled so it can be linked against. Whether this be in your implementation file or separately.

Comment: I was trying to point out that your method is not the only way. There are several ways that work depending on how moc is called.